# Why would a SP 2013 list of 8,500 records impact Site Collection speed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We recently has a SP list that went haywire and a workflow created 8,500 items within the list.  A few days later the Site Collection was extremely slow.  After our SP Admins reviewed a number of potential issues (no blocks, no db issues, etc.) they said for kicks to delete the list that contained 8,500 items.

Once I did (of course I had to delete 100 at a time until I reached 5,000 :( ) then the speed was back to normal for the entire Site Collection.  Why would this impact the Site Collection and why several days later  ?  Our Site Collection has very few documents a this time so I am perplexed on why this created an issue.  I have an MS Access background and 8,500 records is a pittance to run a query against.  What am I missing and more importantly what was my root cause ?

Answer (score 0):

**Boundaries:**

```
File Size: 2GB per item.
Document Count: A flat count of 30,000,000 items per library
Item Count: This is also limited to 30,000,000 items per list.
Bulk Operations: Users are restricted to 100 items per bulk upload.
```

**Thresholds:**

```
List View Threshold: 5,000 items per view.
Admin View Threshold: 5,000 items per view.
Co-author limits: 10 concurrent editors per document (although the maximum supported is 99).
```

So Because of Threshold Limits in List Querying more than 5000 items would not be possible so for viewing 8,500 Threshold of List must have been increased or turned OFF

> **TURN OFF THE LIST VIEW THRESHOLD**
>
> I don’t recommend this option, and neither does Microsoft. The
>   thresholds are in place to help keep your environment performing well.
>   Ignoring this by simply turning off the thresholds is a recipe for
>   poor performance and unhappy users.
>
> **CHANGE THE LIST VIEW THRESHOLD LIMITS**
>
> While this can be done easily in Central Administration, and it is a
>   better option than turning off the threshold limits all together, this
>   is still not a great option. However, this is an easy way to postpone
>   the issue while you figure out the long-term solution. The Threshold
>   limits can be changed in Central Administration under your Web
>   Application settings.
>
> http://www.abelsolutions.com/2013-blog/working-with-list-view-thresholds-in-sharepoint/

This would solve your doubt of site getting slow.

Comment: for clarification my question was not asking about boundaries or limits.  I am familiar with both.  In fact my tech team sent me your cut and paste when I first created the site to ensure I was familiar with list limitations.  my question is why a single list beyond its threshold is a drag on the entire site collection.